# php get foldername and filename of current file but from external script?

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP programmer but I need to get the current file name and parent folder name when using an included script (`require_once(myscript)`)

I know that `basename(__DIR__)` and `basename(__FILE__)` give me the info, BUT! from the running script, which in turn returns a different result e.g:

Consider the following folder structure:

```
/index.php 
/other.php 
/dir/util.php
```

if i have the function below in *util.php*

```
  public static function echoParentAndFileNames(){
      echo basename(__DIR__) . "<br />";
      echo basename(__FILE__) . "<br />";
  }
```

And I run the code bellow in *index.php*

```
require_once("dir/util.php");

Util::echoParentAndFileNames();
```

The output will be: **dir** and **util.php** and I want index.php and its parent folder name ...

So how can I call this script from an included file and have it show me the required  info ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refer to current executing script you can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`.

So, you can change your function to:

```
public static function echoParentAndFileNames(){
    echo basename( dirname( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) . "<br />";
    echo basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) . "<br />";
}
```

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'SCRIPT_FILENAME'
>   The absolute pathname of the currently executing script.
>
> Note:
>   If a script is executed with the CLI, as a relative path, such as file.php or ../file.php, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] will contain the relative path specified by the user.